# Java 2D Game rotate to mouse glitch?

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am making a game in Java (No Libraries).
It's a 2D top-down game where the player can walk and is faced towards the mouse cursor.

```
public Player(int x, int y, int health, int tileId) {
    super(x, y, health);
    tile = new Tile(tileId, false);
    mouseInput = new MouseHandler(screen);
}
public void tick() { // Executed by game tick.
    // x = playerX and y = playerY

    int cursorX = mouseInput.getMousePos()[0];
    int cursorY = mouseInput.getMousePos()[1];

    float X = cursorX - x;
    float Y = cursorY - y;

    rotation = Math.atan2(Y, X);
}
```

It looks good as long the player is at (0,0)
If the player moves and the mouse coordinates become negative it begins to show strange behaviour (Look at video below)

```
Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6ZHCrWvt3Y
```

The rotation of the sprite is done in another class 'Screen.java'

By using:

```
if (rotation < 360)
    rotation++
else
    rotation = 0
```

I verified that the rotation is working correctly.

EDIT:

```
public BufferedImage rotate(BufferedImage img, double degree) {
    AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
    tx.rotate(degree, 4, 4);

    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx,AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage image = op.filter(img,null);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: both variables are named `xd` please post your actual code snippet including the usage code

Comment: @BeyelerStudios Updated my post.

Comment: The code you posted doesnt look like it has any glaring problems in it. Its possible that you are not using the rotation correctly. Can you post the code where you use the `rotation` and actually draw the character. Additionally when debugging things of this nature it can be beneficial to show your current rotation on the screen in some meaningful fashion. *Also looking at your current edit; `Math.atan2` is in radians not degrees*

Comment: @ug_ I edited my question with my rotation code. In the render function i get the player pixels and put it in the screen pixels.
The i iterate over it and render it. There is no problem with that.
About the mouse upperleft corner = (0,0) and downright corner = (screenWidth, screenHeight)

I know Math.atan2 is in radians

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it.

The problem was the game scale i am making an 2d game and set the width, height and the scale.
But i didn't divide the mouseX and mouseY by the scale.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    mouseX = e.getX() / game.getScale();
    mouseY = e.getY() / game.getScale();
}
```

I found the problem by accident when messing with the gamescale.